# Fill missing values in a data frame with the nearest row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {3002: 10001,
  3003: 10002,
  3004: 10003,
  3005: 10004,
  3006: 10005,
  3007: 10006,
  3008: 10007,
  3009: 10008,
  3010: 10009,
  3011: 10010,
  3012: 10011,
  3013: 10012,
  3014: 10013,
  3015: 10014,
  3016: 10015,
  3017: 10016,
  3018: 10017,
  3019: 10018,
  3020: 10019,
  3021: 10020},
 'value': {3002: 1669.0,
  3003: 1264.0,
  3004: nan,
  3005: 1411.0,
  3006: 1224.0,
  3007: 1316.0,
  3008: 1736.0,
  3009: nan,
  3010: 1276.0,
  3011: nan,
  3012: nan,
  3013: nan,
  3014: nan,
  3015: 1790.0,
  3016: nan,
  3017: nan,
  3018: nan,
  3019: 1726.0,
  3020: nan,
  3021: nan}})
```

And I want to fill the missing values with the one in the nearest id, in case of two values at the same distance then I want to use the average.

E.G.

id 10008 is NaN, then I want to fill the cell with the average of  10009 and 10007: (1736.0 + 1276.0)/2

for id 10015 the nearest value is at 10014 so I'll use that value directly: 1790.0

[image]

How can I accomplish this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but you can use [interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) (can only be used on Series):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].interpolate(method='slinear').interpolate(method='linear')
```

The second interpolation is only needed to fill the last NaNs in the series.

Comment: Right, why is that?

Comment: Why the second interpolation is needed? 'slinear' needs a start and an end point to fill the missing values in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.value = df.value.interpolate(method='nearest')
```

Comment: I haven't seen your answer, but the 'nearest'-method does not give you a mean.